# SQL Server Padding 0's with RIGHT Not Working

Tags: sql-server, padding, string-concatenation

I am using SQL Server 2008.

I have a varchar(30) column which holds check numbers.  If the payment was made using a credit card, checknbr will be a zero-length string.  I need to pad this data with leading zeroes such that the entire output is ten digits long.  If there is no check number, it should just be ten zeroes.

Here is the data I would like to see:

```
    0000000000
    0000000000
    0000000114
    0000000105
    0000000007
```

Here is the query I have been using and am stuck on:

```
    SELECT RIGHT((CASE  
        WHEN LEN(checknbr) = 0 THEN '0000000000'
        ELSE '0000000000'+checknbr
    END),10) as checknbr
    FROM payhistory
    WHERE number = 12345678
```

And this is what I get:

```
    0000000000
    0000000000
    114
    105
    7
```

Trying another way:

```
    SELECT RIGHT('0000000000'+checknbr,10)
    FROM payhistory
    WHERE number = 3861821
```

And I get the same results.  Oddly enough, I have a varchar(10) column where

```
    RIGHT('0000'+EDC.DatabaseNumber,4)
```

yields exactly the results I am after.  What am I missing here? Something about a quirk with the RIGHT function?

Thanks in advance

Comment: How are you observing the results?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using SQL server 2012 or up try the following:

```
SELECT RIGHT(CONCAT('0000000000', checknbr), 10)
```

Concat will automatically convert `NULL` values to empty strings, removing the need for extra checks.

By the way, the issue you're having is the fact that your query still sees `checknbr` as a number instead of a `varchar` value. Casting it to `varchar` will solve that for you.

**EDIT SQL Server 2008:**

Since you have a VARCHAR column with no NULL values the only thing that still comes to mind are trailing spaces. Try:

```
SELECT RIGHT('0000000000' + RTRIM(checknbr), 10);
```

Comment: Sorry for confusion.  I am using SQL Server 2008 and have edited my post to clarify.

As for the conversion issue, I don't understand how the query can view checknbr as a number when it is a varchar(30) column already.  When I CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),checknbr) and do the same query, I still get the same results.

Comment: @LegalEagle In that case it's rather curious. Have you checked your values for trailing spaces? `RTRIM(checknbr)`

Comment: You solved it!!  Using RTRIM(checknbr) in my CONVERT statement fixed it!!!  THANK YOU!!!!

Comment: @LegalEagle Happy to help. Those trailing spaces are rather troublesome though. If I were you I'd try to get rid of the root cause, otherwise you'll always have to be extra on your toes.

Answer (score 0):

using `cast()` or `convert()` to convert `checknbr` to a character value will solve the implicit conversion of `'0000000000'` to the integer `0`.

```
select right('0000000000'+convert(varchar(10),checknbr),10)
from payhistory
where number = 3861821
```

If `checknbr` can be `null` and you want it to return as `'0000000000'`, then you can wrap it in `coalesce()` or `isnull()`:

```
select right('0000000000'+isnull(convert(varchar(10),checknbr),''),10)
from payhistory
where number = 3861821
```

---

If `checknbr` is not a number, but `varchar(30)`, then (as Jens points out), you may have padded spaces that need to be trimmed:

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/IRLV83801

```
create table payhistory (checknbr varchar(30));
insert into payhistory values ('0'), ('1'), ('         0'), ('0         '),('          ');

select checknbr = right('0000000000'+checknbr,10)
from payhistory
```

returns:

```
+------------+
|  checknbr  |
+------------+
| 0000000000 |
| 0000000001 |
|          0 |
| 0          |
|            |
+------------+
```

And if you trim the padded spaces:

```
select checknbr = right('0000000000'+ltrim(rtrim(checknbr)),10)
from payhistory
```

returns:

```
+------------+
|  checknbr  |
+------------+
| 0000000000 |
| 0000000001 |
| 0000000000 |
| 0000000000 |
| 0000000000 |
+------------+
```

Comment: I just tried this:

`SELECT RIGHT('0000000000'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),checknbr),10)
FROM payhistory
WHERE number = 3861821`

and it yielded exactly the same results in my original post.

Checknbr is an empty string when there is no value.  There are no nulls in that column.