# Padding zero with minimum SQL

Tags: zero-padding

SQL statement to achieve following logic with minimum length 5

For example:
2.34 to be 2.340

0.158787 to be  0.158787 and
.2 to be 0.200 and
5 to be  00005
2093 to be 02093 and 78934 to be 78934

Tried LPAD,LTRIM and REPLACE

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43412377/sql-server-padding-0s-with-right-not-working

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL Server Padding 0's with RIGHT Not Working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43412377/sql-server-padding-0s-with-right-not-working)